# It is possible to set static time into UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

I am using `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` for background fetch for updating UI. But I know that system decides when to call its method `Performfetchwithcompletionhandler` So, sometime it may take 10 min or more or less than 10 min.

I want to set static time into minimum fetch or calling method within 3 minutes. So is there any possibility that I can set 3 minutes into `minimumfetchtimeinterval` ?

I really appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS will determine when to give your app a chance to perform a background fetch, based on how frequently your background fetch results in new data and the energy impact of your background fetch.

You cannot specify a specific interval. Specifying `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` will result in the most frequent background fetch.

Comment: Yeah, I know that system decides when to call performfetchcompletionhandler, So how can I do it for minimum 3 minute interval ? I want to update UI for every 3 minutes. please help me with it

Comment: You can't. You can use remote push to trigger your app, but even then if you send too many pushes iOS will limit the rate at which they are delivered to your app. in mobile apps you should use push rather than polling; it isn't battery or network use friendly